# Where can I find the side by side compilation of the vedic verses and their tamil counterparts from Nalayira Divya Prabhandham?

Tags: vedas, sri-vaishnava, alwar, tamil, divya-prabhandham

We have the Naalaayira Divyaprabhandham in Tamil, a composition of 4000 verses from 12 Alwars. Among them, Nammalwar is considered as "One who gave the vedas in Tamil" through 1352 verses of the 4000. Is there a side by side compilation of the vedic verses and their prabhandham equivalents?

Comment: Great question. The Nalayira Divya Prabandham has very deep Tattvas, and it is called Dravida Veda. The idea here is that it is in harmony with the teachings of Vedanta. I don't know of any such mapping work which maps Tamil verses to Upanishadic verses.


Vedanta Desika Acharya has written a great number of Sanskrit and Tamil works which touch on Upanishads as well as the Prabandham.

Comment: Yes, I know. I have heard Velukkudi Krishnan swami talk about such instances of tamil prabhandhams exactly stating vedic verses in many of his upanyasams. Unfortunately, I can neither remember in which ones nor have I recorded those since I hear them mostly on the move. I was hoping someone has actually recorded such instances personally or know some book that does it.

Comment: I dont think its verse by verse Vedas in Tamil but based on vedic knowledge

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Oh I didn't mean that every verse from the vedas had its Tamil prabhandham. Whatever is there, I was seeing if someone had the quick lookup type of reference.